# Why $1$ is the only quadratic residue modulo $8$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to understand the Proposition 5.1.1 - Ireland and Rosen, A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory, p.50, however, I can't understand why this argument is true:
$1$ is the only quadratic residue mod $8$.
I wrote a program to generate all quadratic residue modulo $8$, from $0$ to $7$

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
4 -> 4
9 -> 1
16 -> 0
25 -> 1
36 -> 4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I saw $4$ there, so how come only $1$ satisfied?

The original text was,
[image]

Thank you,

@Bill Dubuque: Thank you for the reference.

Comment: note the $(a,m)=1$ part of the hypothesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quadratic residues are usually taken from the unit group. $2$ is not in $U_8$.
The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Composite_modulus_not_a_prime_power) mentions this issue, citing Ireland and Rosen.

Comment: So how can we determine which number is in unit group? Thank you.

Comment: @Chan, by definition, those coprime with $m$.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now.

Comment: @Chan, btw, note the hypothesis $(a,m)=1$ in the proposition you cited.